# How do I create custom user permissions?

Tags: python, django, user-permissions

I have a model form, that is used to request a leave from a employees perspective. I want another user to either accept or reject the leave, for this purpose, I have a boolean field dedicated to it.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES, default = None)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
    permission = models.BooleanField(('status'), default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Now my goal is to make a custom permission such that another user can read-only rest of the fields except the "permission" field, where he can either accept or reject. 
I've tried using programmatically creating user permissions which reflected in the User Permissions Panel but didn't function as I wanted.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from .models import Leave


content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Leave)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
   codename='can_change_status',
   name='Can Change Status',
   content_type=content_type,
)
```

Please help me in completing my project, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):     
        if obj and request.user.is_staff:
            readonly_fields = [f.name for f in self.opts.fields]
            readonly_fields.remove('permission')    
        return readonly_fields
```

Add this in your admin.py under class ....(ModelAdmin)